# Is this an infinite do loop in fortran syntax?

Tags: fortran

```
do

  lineNumber = lineNumber + 1

end do
```

Is this an infinite loop in fortran? I'm not familiar with the syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is valid a Fortran snippet, but I don't get the purpose of this.

Comment: This was just a simple example. The contents of the do loop were actually much more complicated, but for the purpose of posting I simplified it because I really just wanted to know what this did.

Comment: Is this pretty much equivalent to (in C/C++)
while (true)
{
  lineNumber = lineNumber + 1;
}